# Meteor update JQuery plugin data

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a Meteor app using Blaze templates designed to power a diary, with the display part handled by JQuery FullCalendar.  I am passing fullcalendar a callback to use for the events to display, which is working well.  I can't get this to behave in a reactive fashion though - the diary will be used on several devices simultaneously and I want the event to be updated on all devices immediately.  I am able to update the collection, I can see the changes being pushed to the minimongo subscription however I can't get the calendar to update.  Is there an event I can hook into where I can force the calendar to refetch the events?  It seems like this should be a fairly common use case?

Current code is as follows:

Diary.js:

```
Template.Diary.onCreated(function() {
    this.autorun(() => {
        this.subscribe('bookings');
    });
});

Template.Diary.helpers({
    dataReady : function() {
      return Template.instance().subscriptionsReady();
    },
    events: function () {
        const instance = Template.instance();
        var fc = $('.fc');
        return function (start, end, tz, callback) {
                //console.log(instance.data.bookings);
                //find all, because we've already subscribed to a specific range
                var events = Bookings.find().map(function (bk) {
                    return {
                        title: bk.serviceName,
                        start: bk.bookingDate,
                        editable: bk.bookingDate > new Date(),
                        allDay: false
                    };
                });
                console.log(events);
                callback(events);
        };
    },
    onEventClicked: function() {
        return function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            alert("Event clicked: "+calEvent.title);
        }
    }
});

Template.Diary.rendered = function () {
    const instance = Template.instance();
    var fc = this.$('.fc');

    this.autorun(function () {
        console.log("refetching events");
        fc.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    });
};
```

The code `console.log("refetching events");` is only ever called once, it is this I need to be called whenever the bookings subscription changes.

Diary.html (additional markup removed):

```
{{#if dataReady}}
    {{> fullcalendar
            class="fc"
            defaultView='agendaWeek'
            height="100%"
            events=events
            eventClick=onEventClicked
    }}
{{else}}
    <div class="calendar_loading">Loading...</div>
{{/if}}
```

The actual FullCalendar display is in it's own component which was based from the one packaged on Atmosphere - I'm likely to be customising this quite heavily and also wanted control over the plugin versions hence not using directly.  This component is as follows:

fullcalendar.js:

```
Template.fullcalendar.rendered = function() {
    var div = this.$(this.firstNode);
    if(this.data != null) {
        div.attr('id', this.data.id);
        div.addClass(this.data.class);
    }
    div.fullCalendar(this.data);
};
```

fullcalendar.html

```
<template name="fullcalendar">
    <div class="fc"></div>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you share your Template definition as well?

Comment: @jordanwillis updated question - I also added the actual fullcalendar component code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think changing your `onRendered` method should solve the issue.

```
Template.Diary.onRendered = function () {
  var self = this;

  this.autorun(function () {
      Bookings.find().fetch();
      var fc = self.$('.fc');
      fc.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
  });
};
```

You must have a reactive data source inside your `autorun` to ensure that it executes when data changes.  In this case we don't actually need to get the data within the `autorun` since you are using the FullCalendar events callback.  So `Bookings.find().fetch()` just ensures each time the collection changes `refetchEvents` is run.

Check out this [tutorial](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/reactive-calendars-with-fullcalendar) in case you need some additional help.

Comment: I've made exactly this change (but left the console.log("refetching events"); in there) and the behaviour is still the same.  I only ever see the "refetching events" message once when the template is rendered

Comment: @Macros Just out of curiosity, try adding `.map()` to your collection find (see updated answer). Otherwise you can try using an observer (I will send that approach when I get back to a computer).

Comment: That looks like it could be on the right track - it throws an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined` however I'm assuming that is to do with the empty args to map.  It does log the message to the console though (it doesn't refresh the calendar but as long as it is calling the code then it should just need fixing to rerender)

Comment: Yes sorry I meant to have you add .fetch() instead of .map(). I just updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Without wanting to wander too far from the original question...it looks like the reactive part is fixed (thanks!) however the calendar is not updating.  If I call the exact same `fc.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');`.  It looks like fc is not being found but the exact same code works fine in a Chrome console.  is there a scope issue here?

Comment: Try moving `var fc = this.$('.fc')` inside the autorun (you won't be able to use `this` though...So store it in a `self` var first outside the autorun). Since fullcalendar doesn't render until after the subscription is ready (which is after `onRendered` has already run) that line is probably not able to get the Element reference yet.

Comment: Exactly what I ended up doing - meant to update.  Thanks!